# Java MVC, Factory and Observer patterns together

Tags: java, model-view-controller, factory, observer-pattern

How should an architecture(packages,classes) of an app that must use the mvc, factory and observer patterns, look like?

The problem is about solving a **labyrinth** that can have two types of implementantions for the Labyrinth(*model*) interface : one that useses a bidimensional array(matrix) and one that uses a sparse matrix(a list that stores only the occupied cells).

The *View* part should be responsible with describing the text representation of a labyrinth. It should contain the methods: get/setLabyrinth, toString. 
I should also have a LabyrinthSolver interface from which I will create two implementations: an interactive one(using the keyboard) and an automated one(lee's algorithm).

The interface *LabyrinthObserver* describes an observer of the labyrinth exploration.
One observer will print on the screen information during the exploration.
One observer will store the solutions found by the exploration in a data structure sorted by the length of the solution.

Finally, the mazes(matrixImpl or sparseImpl) should be created using a *factory*.

I am having problems when designing the view:
Because I can store a labyrinth in 2 ways(bidimensional matrix or as a List of occupied cells) how should I create the text representation of a labyrinth now knowing how my labyrinth will be stored?
I am thinking about creating an interface with the method

```
createTextRepresentation( ? labyrinth)
```

But what type should my labyrinth parameter be? I have this problem with all my other classes: solver, observer ? 
How can I use these 3 patterns together?

P.S.: I am not asking for the actual implementations for these classes, just a general idea of how should I combine them together.

Answer (score 1):

Since `View` class has setter for labyrinth, `createTextRepresentation` method does not need labyrinth as a parameter.

Your problem is not with designing `View`, it is with design of model. `Labyrinth` interface needs to be expressive enough that text representation can be created using that interface without knowing implementation details.

So code shapes should look like

```
public class LabyrinthFactory {
    public Labyrinth createLabyrinth() { ... }
}

public class LabyrinthView {
    private Labyrinth model; // Avoid getters and setters. Honor encapsulation.

    public LabyrinthView(Labyrinth model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String createTextRepresentation() { ... }
}
```

Comment: And for the observer pattern? I have two observers: one that prints the text representation of the labyrinth after each move of the player and one that will store all the solutions.